# How to connect to mapped/local disk using different credentials?

Tags: c#, windows, io, mapped-drive

I know I can use the [WNetAddConnection2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx) and similar variants to connect to remote shares using custom credentials. I would like to do the same for mapped drives (ex:`\\MyShare\MyFolder` mapped to `Y:`) and my local disks (eg: `C:`,`D:`,`E:`, etc...)
If I point WNetAddConnection to something not `\\` it fails...

Is there a function specific for this scenario???

Answer (score 0):

At work we use a `WindowsImpersonationContext` to handle this situation. Originally we used it in a `VB.NET` `ASP.NET` application, but it is readily modified.

[Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306158) has a great article on how to do it. (We originally used it for Network Drives, but it can be expanded to local disks as well.)

You can basically impersonate a valid user account, which will grant you permissions *that account would have* in the situation. I had to use it to get access to a network drive at work, on a computer that was not a part of the domain. (As such, we had to provide a Username, Domain, and Password for this user account that was not on our domain network and this topic served us well.)

Comment: @Leonardo Can you be specific on how it fails? I'm curious if your setup has anything to do with it.

Comment: actually its a more generic, not involving mapped drives... it only fails on local drives... when i try to copy from folder A to B impersonation User X where A and B do not share the same permissions (eg: X can read from A but not write on B)... so File.Copy crashes...